# How to index and plot contents in a cell array in the same plot?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm hoping someone can help me with this problem.

Initially I was plotting for the arrays *w* and *oLmag* using the following script.

```
figure(1)
for i=1:dsize(1)
    subplot(2,1,1);
    semilogx(w,oLmag(i,:),color(i));
    if(i==1), hold; end
end
```

Now I have collected all *oLmag's* generated using different *w's* using cell arrays *oLmag_c* and *w_c* respectively such that *oLmag_c{1}* corresponds to *w_c{1}* and so on. Now I want to plot for all corresponding *oLmag's* and *w's* in one plot.

```
hold all;
for i=1:dsize(1)
    for k=1:length(w)
        subplot(2,1,1);
        semilogx(w{k},oLmag{k}(i,:),color(i));
        if(i==1); hold; end
     end;
 end
```

This doesn't seem like holding together all plots and produces only one plot. Also I want to have legend on each plot like 1,2...saying 1 stands for *w_c{1}* and *oLmag_c{1}* plot and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second code block, *hold* is called twice.  Once at the start with *hold all* then a second time in the first iteration of the loop

```
if(i==1); hold; end
```

The second call to *hold* toggles the hold state of the current axes. This probably explains why you only get one plot.

I would change your approach to calling *hold on* or _hold(gca,'on') at the start and deleting the second call to hold inside the nested loops (line 6 of the second code block).

So, after adding sample data and removing line 6 the code block could read something like

```
%# First setup the axes and set 'hold on'
hAxes(1) = subplot(2,1,1)
hAxes(2) = subplot(2,1,2)
hold(hAxes,'on'); %# Using the function form of hold instead
%#hold all 

%# some sample data
w={[1 2] [3 4] [4 5]}; 
oLmag={[22.9983 16.8412; 22.3405 16.1763], ...
       [16.7192 14.0807;14.2588 11.4160], ...
       [12 13;15 14]}; 

 %# nested loops for plotting
 for k=1:length(oLmag) 
    for i=1:length(oLmag{k}) 
        xy=[w{k};oLmag{k}(i,:)]; 
        subplot(2,1,1);
        semilogx(w{k},oLmag{k}(i,:)); 
        subplot(2,1,2);
        %# add plots to second axes here...

        %#if(i==1);hold;end; %# remove extra call to hold
    end;
end
```

Comment: w={[1 2] [3 4] [4 5]};
oLmag={[22.9983 16.8412; 22.3405 16.1763],[16.7192 14.0807;14.2588 11.4160],[12 13;15 14]};
 hold(gca,'on');
 %hold all
 for k=1:length(oLmag)
for i=1:length(oLmag{k})
    xy=[w{k};oLmag{k}(i,:)];
   %subplot(2,1,1);semilogx(w{k},oLmag{k}(i,:),color(i));
    subplot(2,1,1);semilogx(xy,color(i));
    if(i==1);hold;end;
    end;end

Comment: @ Azim: Thanks for your reply..I attach above the samples values and codes used so that you can run and see.sorry I tried to indent the codes in lines, but failed.I'm supposed to get 6 lines in the plot,2 for each content in w and oLmag cell. But this code produces only 4 lines. i think things don't fall at the right place.Hope to hear from you. Thanks

Comment: you can remove colon from the line xy=[w{k};oLmag{k}(i,:)] to see what I'm trying to plot...Thanks